# record application audio only with ffmpeg on macOS

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg

I’m trying to record the audio produced by the system (i.e. from the OS and other running apps) using ffmpeg.

I first create a virtual input/output device using [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole/) or [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/). I then start playback of a file using iTunes, and try recording thus (based on what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590500/ffmpeg-record-output-audio-for-mac) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682144/capturing-only-desktop-audio-with-ffmpeg)):

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i default output.aiff
```

but this produces an error `default: Input/output error`

How can I capture system audio using ffmpeg?

Comment: Hi Eric, did you search for `recording system audio ffmpeg mac` or `ffmpeg input output error`? If so, could you please include what you've found, tried and how it didn't resolve your issue? This help people give you an answer that you didn't try already.

Comment: Hi @SaaruLindestøkke. Yes, I did google for the problem. In fact the command I included in my question comes from the various posts I found. However none of the posts I found provide a working command for macOS 10.15+

Comment: Great, can you rewrite your question such that it has the link(s) where you found the command? Perhaps those links have state certain conditions that you can't meet on a Mac.
Also, if you open Quicktime, then `File -> New Audio Recording`, are you able to select the Loopback device and record the audio from iTunes? That way you can verify if the Loopback device is set-up correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to select the Loopback device from Quicktime and record audio from iTunes.

Comment: Can you include in your question all avfoundation audiodevices found with `ffmpeg avfoundation -list_devices`?
Your command expects a screen and audio device index after the `-i` argument, and you can find the right device index with the `-list_devices` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To record from the default audio device:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" test-output.aiff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command uses `default` for the `-i` argument.
The [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#macOS) states that argument `-i` expects a screen and audio device index. As you're not providing an index but a word `default` it's throwing an error.

The documentation explains how you can find those indices:

> Use the avfoundation device:
>
> `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`
> This will enumerate all the available input devices including screens ready to be
> captured.
>
> Once you've figured out the device index corresponding to the screen
> to be captured, use:
>
> `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "<screen device index>:<audio device index>" output.mkv`
>
> This will capture the screen from `<screen device index>` and
> audio from `<audio device index>` into the output file `output.mkv`.

In your case you're not looking for a screen device index, but for an audio device index.

Comment: Yes, I was familiar with the documentation. What I needed was the correct syntax of the command.

Comment: @Eric Nowhere in the question do you state that you've read the documentation, so how could I've known that you were familiar with it? I think this is an excellent example of why you should include all research you've done so far such that answerers don't waste time on looking up stuff you've already seen.

Comment: If the question contains a relatively sophisticated attempt at solving the problem, I think it's safe to assume the OP read the documentation. And if you care to read [this site's documentation](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), you'll note that answers should actually... "answer the question".

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the site's docs that one should answer the question fully. It does say: `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful`, which is what I did (based on your question content). I doubt it's safe to assume the knowledge of OP, that's also why [the guide on asking question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) states `Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.` If you would've said: I've read the docs, but can't find how I select the default audio device, it would be a different question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 2021 macbook.

Comment: Could you indicate what part gives you trouble? Are you not able to get a list of devices? Or does the capturing fail while you've pointed it to the desired device?

Answer (score 1):

To record from the default device you can do this:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":default" test-output.mp3
```

The output file is `test-output.mp3`.

Comment: (1) Since the guts of your answer is only one character different from what the OP posted in the question, it would be clearer if you *said* “you have to put a colon at the beginning of the `-i` argument.” (2) How is `:default` different from `:0`? (3) Why not just use the OP’s output filename? Are you saying that it’s better to capture to a `.mp3` file than an ``.aiff`` file? Why?